# HTML/CSS/JS not displaying slideshows pictures

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I basically just copied the slideshow tutorials from W3schools, i see the pictures when i inspect the page but the actual images are not displaying on the website. I can't figure out if I missed a div or something. I am getting the images with PHP, 3 images are the same just to test it.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" />
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" />
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" />
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are your image paths are correct?

Comment: Did you copied the images too into */images* folder..?

Comment: yes I can see the pictures when i inspect the page

Comment: can you put whole code in your question?

Comment: There should me some style on `.mySlides` which prevent images to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may missing the the width attribute for images in src. Use it like this, it might work.

```
<div class="mySlides fade" >
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" style="width:100%" />
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that actually did the opposite, i can't the pictures even when I inspect the page

Comment: can you send the link of w3schools from where you have copied this line of code.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Comment: then I think you are missing width on the image. Use this line it will must work.
<img src="images/<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" style="width:100%" />

Comment: only one image is displayed at a time, very buggy

Comment: @cheunology image is not displaying on website because your main div having 'fade' class have css 'opacity: 0;'. set it to 1. like this 'opacity: 1;'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203725/discussion-between-cheunology-and-dinkar-kumar).

Comment: @cheunology -  or remove fade class from parent div. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add Javascript. Try this in the footer

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes I copied all css and js from the W3 tutorials, i just didn't want paste all of the codes on here. But i have everything

Comment: Can you make **codepen** for checking code?
https://codepen.io/

Comment: Use this in css and check 
.mySlides.fade {opacity: 1;}

Comment: that fixed the main problem but i have mulplite products on the page and only 1 image at a time is showing

Answer (score 0):

Css Class fade https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/less/component-animations.less
have opacity 0 which is overriding your class fade.
change your css class to this

```
.fade{
webkit-animation-name: fade !important;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s !important; 
    animation-name: fade !important;
    animation-duration: 1.5s !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;

}
```